# Show that if $x_0$ is a local extreme point of $f$, then $ |f(x_0)| = \left[ 1 + (n^2-1) \sin^2(x_0) \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

> "Show that if $x_0$ is a local extreme point of $f$:
>   $$f(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{n \sin x}$$, with $x \neq k \pi$, $k \in \mathbb Z$, $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, then:
>
> $$ |f(x_0)| = \left[ 1 + (n^2-1) \sin^2(x_0) \right]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
>
> Hint: Express $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ in term of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ and add their squares to obtain a useful identity"

The derivative $f$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(\sin nx)'(n \sin x)-(\sin nx)(n \sin x)'}{(n \sin x)^2}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{(n \cos nx)(n \sin x)-(\sin nx)(n \cos x)}{(n \sin x)^2}$$

Express $\sin nx$  in term of $f(x)$:
$$\sin nx = f(x) \cdot (n \sin x)$$

Express $\cos nx$:

$$f'(x)=\frac{(n \cos nx)(n \sin x)-(\sin nx)(n \cos x)}{(n \sin x)^2}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{(n \cos nx)(n \sin x)-[f(x) \cdot (n \sin x)](n \cos x)}{(n \sin x)^2}$$

$$(n \sin x)f'(x)+(n \cos x)f(x)=(n \cos nx)$$

Squaring and Sum:
$$(\cos nx)^2+(\sin nx)^2=1$$

$$[(\sin x)f'(x)+(\cos x)f(x)]^2+ [ f(x) \cdot (n \sin x) ] ^2 =1$$

From that point, I do not know how to proceed.

I understood that local extreme points $x_0$ are such that $x_0 \in D_f$, $f'(x_0)=0$ ...

What would be a good approach here?

Much appreciated.

Comment: (Hint) Set your expression for $f'(x_0) = 0$

Comment: I did that but i did not see any result reaching to the targeted proposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you do not mind if I restart from scratch, I do not like differentiating ratios. For any $x\not\in \pi\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$ \sin(nx) = n\sin(x)\,f(x)\tag{1} $$
and by applying $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides

$$\cos(nx) = \sin(x)\,f'(x)+\cos(x)\,f(x) \tag{2}$$
so by squaring $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$ 1 = \left[n^2\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\right]f(x)^2 + f'(x)\left[\ldots\right]\tag{3} $$
If $x_0\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is a stationary point of $f$ we have $f'(x_0)=0$, so by evaluating $(3)$ at $x=x_0$
$$ 1 = \left[n^2\sin^2(x_0)+1-\sin^2(x_0)\right]\,f(x_0)^2 \tag{4} $$
and the claim is proved.